# Unity launcher / OSX Spotlight like functionality for administration?

Tags: 7

I'm fairly certain I've seen a module that provides a quick way of typing in, for example, the title, of an administrative page, and it would wisk you away to that page.

Much like the way Unity's launcher, OSX's spotlight or KDE's runner behaves, just inside your site instead of the desktop.

However, I can't seem to recall what it was called and google only came up with [this abandoned sandbox](http://drupal.org/sandbox/ptr_prokvk/1244452).

Comment: There's [EazyLaunch](http://drupal.org/project/eazylaunch) but there's also one with a nicer UI which is escaping my mind too right now...

Comment: how about [coffee](http://drupal.org/project/coffee) ? havent tested though. also on some webs the admin menu has a clever searchbox but i cant recall how to switch it on :)

Comment: @mojzis That's the one! It works a treat, you should write that up in an answer :)

Comment: i found coffee in an [article](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/some-tools-to-aid-your-drupal-admin-pain/2012-02-22) from wunderkraut. But if remember well, i wasnt exactly happy with it, because it went to search for stuff on the server, while the admin thing is based on going through links in the admin menu, which is sort of clever :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While [coffee](http://drupal.org/project/coffee) is probably the module you are looking for, i think switching on search in admin_menu is way more productive - no roundtrip for the searches and you stay focused on the admin stuff. I bet you are using the admin_menu anyway ? Just visit `admin/config/administration/admin_menu` and hit save - the search field should appear on the right hand side of the admin menu :)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know admin_menu had that feature. It's terribly annoying though that I can't use it with the keyboard only. Both starting a search and picking search results require the mouse. Coffee on the other hand, works exactly like I want/expect. I'll leave the Q open a while longer to see if any alternatives pop up. Thanks!

Comment: @Letharion, you are right, that sounds like a call for a patch :)